# Redirect Jmeter to the home page after successful login with multiple users

Tags: jmeter

I created a script multiple user logins and redirected to the home page. For multiple user logins fetching data from CSV file but after logged in, home page redirection is not working.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible explanations:

1. Your login fails somewhere somehow so you're still at the login page, check the server response using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and if this is the case - fix your script. It might be sufficient to add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to represent user session
2. You might need to play with `Redirect automatically` / `Follow redirects` checkboxes on [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler level

   [image]
3. Your redirect is being managed by JavaScript and JMeter is not capable of executing JavaScript so you need to extract the desired redirect location using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) (basically implement [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) of the redirect URL) and add another HTTP Request sampler to open the redirect target.

More information: [Redirections in HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)

In general make sure that JMeter sends the same requests as the real browser does, given this simple rule is met you should be able to properly simulate real user actions